# How to use .htaccess file to redirect old URL (with article id) to new URL (without article id)?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a Joomla-based website using K2 (CCK) for content creation. Joomla is updated to J4. It is a major release of Joomla and unfortunately, the K2 team is not updating the K2 for making it J4 compatible. So I have moved all the articles to Zoo (CCK).

Now the problem is with the URLs. The structure of the old URL is as `example.com/topics/category/item/12345678-this-is-the-article-alias`

after migration the new URLs are `example.com/topics/category/item/this-is-the-article-alias`. I have Googled but have not found any method to redirect old URLs to new URLs. I just want to remove the article id (numbers/digits) with `-` which is just after the word `item/` and before the first `-` coming after the word `item/` in the old URL.

I have tried the rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)item/(\d+\-)?(.*) /$1$3 [R=301,L]` but it is removing **item/** as well from the URL and I want to keep it, just want to only remove article id.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)item/(\d+\-)?(.*) /$1$3 [R=301,L]

Comment: Not in comment, please edit your question and put it there

Comment: it is not redirecting as I want. It is removing the item/ as well from the link, but I want to keep it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually pretty close.
You may use this rule to redirect. **Make sure to keep this rule at the top after `RewriteEngine On` line:**

```bash
RewriteRule ^(.+/item/)\d+-(.+)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

---

You tried this rule:

```bash
RewriteRule ^(.*)item/(\d+\-)?(.*) /$1$3 [R=301,L]
```

Which is matching `item/` but **not capturing** in any of the capture groups hence it is left out in target.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following .htaccess rules. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. This is doing external redirect for URL as per requirement.

```bash
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(topics/category/item)/[^-]*-(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]
```